# Regularization on divergent series

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, divergent-series, regularization

I want to  compute $$ \sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac {\left( 2n+k-2\right) !\zeta \left( 2n\right) \left( -1\right) ^{n-1}}{\left( 2\pi \right) ^{2n}}. $$

This series is surely not convergent for any value of $k$,but moreover it is a divergent series. We shall assign a value to this series by adapted Borel sums. It also grows faster than $n^{2n}$.I need a function depended on "k" This series might be considered from a different angle.I think regularized Borel-sum works ,perhaps you guys give me a little help to simplify this series

Comment: $\zeta(2n) = (-1)^{n+1} B_{2n} (2\pi)^{2n} / 2(2n)! $ so that the summands simplify to $\frac{(2n+k-2)!}{2(2n)!} B_{2n}$ which is always positive and goes to infinity. It seems to me that the only reasonable value for the series is $+\infty$, no matter what kind of regularisation you're thinking about.

Comment: İf we let k be zero the series can be computed by Norlound sum the result is something like 0.0405307... İn deed ,I didnt get the series adapted for any value of k

Comment: ı realized that this series always alterna series not always positive

Comment: My personal belief always was  that the method of regularization should be determined by the *purpose*  of computing the series, and that the "problem of regularization" has absolutely no meaning by itself . Can you say something about the motivation?

Comment: I am dealing with RH,in the progress former series of this series give the result for any value when $ k>0 $ but also I am not able to prove it coz all series diverge,that is why in my humble opinion, if professionals show the way ,at least I understand that it is eihter the key of RH or not

Comment: It sounded a bit vague. If you are trying to find an approach to RH as I understood it, then this one does not look very promising to me. Anyway, Borel summation of a number series is, more often then not, meaningless. It starts to make sense when interpreted as a special case of a function series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation. You may try to reformulate it this way if you want, and this would be a  better question.

Comment: I actually found a formula that convert a number between 0 and 1 to divergent alterna series ,by some calculation ,I have reached this point,there are  more equations like this one , all I need is a reguralizition but this math is beyond me

Comment: You should ask a more specific question then. (Probably on MSE, because this does not look like a research level mathematics, to me at least.)

Comment: I mean, "Find me the sum of this divergent series somehow" is not a mathematical question, because such a "sum" may (and often does) depend on how it is computed. You cannot expect a reasonable answer on this. If you want to compute it using a prescribed method (e.g. Borel), it makes some sense, but then you better ask a more precise question. (Where, exactly, you are stuck?) A piece of advice: a small but precise  question is better then a big and vague one.

Comment: You are right ,I should have edited as compute the series if it can be summed ,then may I take a suggestion to be informed about borel sum? İf you dont mind

Comment: The most obvious way to use Borel summation here is to take $a_{2n}$ as you have defined and $a_{2n+1}=0$. (In the notation of en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) This should work, at least to some extent.  Did you try it? (If you did, you should have written about this.)